# How to find limit of this product as n tends to infinity?

Tags: limits

> Solve:
> $$ ((({a+1/n})^n)(({a+2/n})^n).....({a+k/n})^n)/a^{nk}. $$
> I have no clue how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try taking logarithms and using a quadratic approximation (with error term) to each term $n\log(1+j/an)$ to find the limit of the sum of logarithms.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

$ 
\begin{align*}
L &= \prod_{i = 1}^k \bigg(1 + \frac{i}{an}\bigg)^n \\
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bigg(1 + \frac{i}{an}\bigg)^n &= \begin{cases}
\infty &,\exists p > 0 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \big(\frac{i}{n^p} \big) \in (0, \infty] \\
e^\frac{i}{a} &,\text{o.w.}
\end{cases} \\
\Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} L &= \begin{cases} \infty &, \exists p > 0 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \big( \frac{k}{n^p} \big) \in (0, \infty] \\
e^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2a}} &,\text{o.w.} \end{cases}
\end{align*} 
$

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is informative!